# Cut Mesh adding a flat surface automatically

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I would like to learn how cut a mesh getting a flat surface automatically, so I can 3d print it on that flat surface, and then, have a nice surface to glue both parts after 3D printing them.

I know how to achieve those results on tinkercad, but there should be a way of achieving this, without leaving blender.

Form this model:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

What I do to fill the rear is boolean a square, to get the inner shape of the rear.

[image]

I get this result

[image]
Then I export the model to tinkercad, and cut it.

I try to do the same thing I do using tinkercad on blender

[image]

But as you can see I get a gap. This is not printable.
[image]

I fill the gap:

[image]

But when I slice the model there is something weird with the model

[image]

Any experts here know how to achieve this propperly without leaving Blender?

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: have you tried the Bisect tool in Edit mode? Also the Line Project in Sculpt mode

Comment: It looks like having used a solidifying modifier instead of starting with a base mesh that is already solidified would have been helpful, but I’m not sure how easy that would be to backpedal or if it would be even possible. Do check out bisect.